# CodeIgniter-like Routes in CherryPy

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy

I'm coming from PHP frameworks, and one thing I like about them is that routing is sort of taken care of for me: I can drop all of my controllers in the directory `controllers` and it will automatically call `Posts::delete(12)` when a user visits `http://www.example.com/posts/delete/12`. I realize that I can use Routes with CherryPy, but I'm kind of annoyed with how limited the documentation is— there's nothing on how I should format my class name (should I call it PostsController()? does it even care?), using `routes.mapper.connect()` vs `routes.connect()`, and what happens when it calls the default route (`/:controller/:action/:id`).

I'd really like to use Python, but I don't want to have to define every single route. Could someone point me to a Python web-framework newb tutorial on how to use Routes or just explain how one goes about structuring a CherryPy web-app so that I can have a couple of Routes laid out like

```
d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.mapper.connect('main', '/:controller/:action', controller='root', action='index')
d.mapper.connect('main', '/:controller/:action/:id', controller='root', action='index')
```

and it will handle it for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to use `cherrypy.tree.mount` to mount a controller object.  The structure of the controller will give you your basic routes.

For example:

```
import cherrypy

class AppRoot:
    def index(self):
        return "App root's index"
    index.exposed = True

    controller1 = Controller1Class()
    # controller2 = Controller2Class(), etc.

class Controller1Class:

     def index(self):
         return "Controller 1's index"
     index.exposed = True

     def action1(self, id):
         return "You passed %s to controller1's action1" % id      
     action1.exposed = True

     # def action2(self, id): etc...

# ... the rest of the config stuff ...

cherrypy.tree.mount(AppRoot(), '/')  

# ... the rest of the startup stuff....
```

Calling the following URIs will call the following methods:

- http://mysite.com/index -> `AppRoot::index()`
- http://mysite.com/controller1 -> `Controller1Class::index()`
- http://mysite.com/controller1/action1 -> `Controller1Class::action1()`
- http://mysite.com/controller1/action1/40 -> `Controller1Class::action1("40")`

See also:

- http://mark.biek.org/blog/2009/07/basic-routing-with-cherrypy/
- http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/PageHandlers